# Replicate functionality of DebugView in .NET - Global Win32 debug hooks?

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, winapi

I'm interested in how plausible it would be to capture Win32 debug traces system-wide in the way DebugView does. I'm not interested in kernel messages thankfully, so I don't need any help there. This needs to be in C#, but I'm happy with unmanaged/unsafe if necessary.

Is there any global hook I can get or am I setting off down a difficult road?

I'm really not sure where the best place is to start on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally got there. It took some serious googling, but I found an article which helped...

All kudos go to Chritian Birkl for his rather excellent Code Project *[DbMon.NET - A simple .NET OutputDebugString capturer](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/trace/DbMonNET.aspx?msg=2811013)*.

The code is pretty heavy-going, but here it is:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public delegate void OnOutputDebugStringHandler(int pid, string text);


public sealed class DebugMonitor
{

    private DebugMonitor()
    {
        ;
    }

    #region Win32 API Imports

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR
    {
        public byte revision;
        public byte size;
        public short control;
        public IntPtr owner;
        public IntPtr group;
        public IntPtr sacl;
        public IntPtr dacl;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
    {
        public int nLength;
        public IntPtr lpSecurityDescriptor;
        public int bInheritHandle;
    }

    [Flags]
    private enum PageProtection : uint
    {
        NoAccess = 0x01,
        Readonly = 0x02,
        ReadWrite = 0x04,
        WriteCopy = 0x08,
        Execute = 0x10,
        ExecuteRead = 0x20,
        ExecuteReadWrite = 0x40,
        ExecuteWriteCopy = 0x80,
        Guard = 0x100,
        NoCache = 0x200,
        WriteCombine = 0x400,
    }


    private const int WAIT_OBJECT_0 = 0;
    private const uint INFINITE = 0xFFFFFFFF;
    private const int ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS = 183;

    private const uint SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR_REVISION = 1;

    private const uint SECTION_MAP_READ = 0x0004;

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr MapViewOfFile(IntPtr hFileMappingObject, uint
        dwDesiredAccess, uint dwFileOffsetHigh, uint dwFileOffsetLow,
        uint dwNumberOfBytesToMap);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool UnmapViewOfFile(IntPtr lpBaseAddress);

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool InitializeSecurityDescriptor(ref SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR sd, uint dwRevision);

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool SetSecurityDescriptorDacl(ref SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR sd, bool daclPresent, IntPtr dacl, bool daclDefaulted);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr CreateEvent(ref SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa, bool bManualReset, bool bInitialState, string lpName);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    private static extern bool PulseEvent(IntPtr hEvent);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    private static extern bool SetEvent(IntPtr hEvent);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr CreateFileMapping(IntPtr hFile,
        ref SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpFileMappingAttributes, PageProtection flProtect, uint dwMaximumSizeHigh,
        uint dwMaximumSizeLow, string lpName);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr hHandle);

    [DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
    private static extern Int32 WaitForSingleObject(IntPtr handle, uint milliseconds);
    #endregion


    public static event OnOutputDebugStringHandler OnOutputDebugString;

    private static IntPtr m_AckEvent = IntPtr.Zero;

    private static IntPtr m_ReadyEvent = IntPtr.Zero;

    private static IntPtr m_SharedFile = IntPtr.Zero;

    private static IntPtr m_SharedMem = IntPtr.Zero;

    private static Thread m_Capturer = null;

    private static object m_SyncRoot = new object();

    private static Mutex m_Mutex = null;


    public static void Start()
    {
        lock (m_SyncRoot)
        {
            if (m_Capturer != null)
                throw new ApplicationException("This DebugMonitor is already started.");

            if (Environment.OSVersion.ToString().IndexOf("Microsoft") == -1)
                throw new NotSupportedException("This DebugMonitor is only supported on Microsoft operating systems.");

            bool createdNew = false;
            m_Mutex = new Mutex(false, typeof(DebugMonitor).Namespace, out createdNew);
            if (!createdNew)
                throw new ApplicationException("There is already an instance of 'DbMon.NET' running.");

            SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR sd = new SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR();

            if (!InitializeSecurityDescriptor(ref sd, SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR_REVISION))
            {
                throw CreateApplicationException("Failed to initializes the security descriptor.");
            }

            if (!SetSecurityDescriptorDacl(ref sd, true, IntPtr.Zero, false))
            {
                throw CreateApplicationException("Failed to initializes the security descriptor");
            }

            SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa = new SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES();

            m_AckEvent = CreateEvent(ref sa, false, false, "DBWIN_BUFFER_READY");
            if (m_AckEvent == IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                throw CreateApplicationException("Failed to create event 'DBWIN_BUFFER_READY'");
            }

            m_ReadyEvent = CreateEvent(ref sa, false, false, "DBWIN_DATA_READY");
            if (m_ReadyEvent == IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                throw CreateApplicationException("Failed to create event 'DBWIN_DATA_READY'");
            }

            m_SharedFile = CreateFileMapping(new IntPtr(-1), ref sa, PageProtection.ReadWrite, 0, 4096, "DBWIN_BUFFER");
            if (m_SharedFile == IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                throw CreateApplicationException("Failed to create a file mapping to slot 'DBWIN_BUFFER'");
            }

            m_SharedMem = MapViewOfFile(m_SharedFile, SECTION_MAP_READ, 0, 0, 512);
            if (m_SharedMem == IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                throw CreateApplicationException("Failed to create a mapping view for slot 'DBWIN_BUFFER'");
            }

            m_Capturer = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Capture));
            m_Capturer.Start();
        }
    }

    private static void Capture()
    {
        try
        {
            IntPtr pString = new IntPtr(
                m_SharedMem.ToInt32() + Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(int))
            );

            while (true)
            {
                SetEvent(m_AckEvent);

                int ret = WaitForSingleObject(m_ReadyEvent, INFINITE);

                if (m_Capturer == null)
                    break;

                if (ret == WAIT_OBJECT_0)
                {
                    FireOnOutputDebugString(
                        Marshal.ReadInt32(m_SharedMem),
                            Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(pString));
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;

        }
        finally
        {
            Dispose();
        }
    }

    private static void FireOnOutputDebugString(int pid, string text)
    {
        if (OnOutputDebugString == null)
            return;

        #if !DEBUG
            try
            {
        #endif

                OnOutputDebugString(pid, text);

        #if !DEBUG
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("An 'OnOutputDebugString' handler failed to execute: " + ex.ToString());
            }
        #endif
    }


    private static void Dispose()
    {
        if (m_AckEvent != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            if (!CloseHandle(m_AckEvent))
            {
                throw CreateApplicationException("Failed to close handle for 'AckEvent'");
            }
            m_AckEvent = IntPtr.Zero;
        }

        if (m_ReadyEvent != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            if (!CloseHandle(m_ReadyEvent))
            {
                throw CreateApplicationException("Failed to close handle for 'ReadyEvent'");
            }
            m_ReadyEvent = IntPtr.Zero;
        }

        if (m_SharedFile != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            if (!CloseHandle(m_SharedFile))
            {
                throw CreateApplicationException("Failed to close handle for 'SharedFile'");
            }
            m_SharedFile = IntPtr.Zero;
        }


        if (m_SharedMem != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            if (!UnmapViewOfFile(m_SharedMem))
            {
                throw CreateApplicationException("Failed to unmap view for slot 'DBWIN_BUFFER'");
            }
            m_SharedMem = IntPtr.Zero;
        }

        if (m_Mutex != null)
        {
            m_Mutex.Close();
            m_Mutex = null;
        }
    }

    public static void Stop()
    {
        lock (m_SyncRoot)
        {
            if (m_Capturer == null)
                throw new ObjectDisposedException("DebugMonitor", "This DebugMonitor is not running.");
            m_Capturer = null;
            PulseEvent(m_ReadyEvent);
            while (m_AckEvent != IntPtr.Zero)
                ;
        }
    }

    private static ApplicationException CreateApplicationException(string text)
    {
        if (text == null || text.Length < 1)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("text", "'text' may not be empty or null.");

        return new ApplicationException(string.Format("{0}. Last Win32 Error was {1}",
            text, Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you bother to create a SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR?  You dont set it in the SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES anywhere.  The NULL in the Attributes struct grants default access associated with the calling process.  By default, the default DACL in the access token of a process allows access only to the user represented by the access token.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379560(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use `IntPtr.ToInt64` instead of `IntPtr.ToInt32` for adding the 4 bytes to the message string? On 64 bit systems, the 32 bit conversion could lead to an overflow. Though it works fine on my system right now (with almost 5 out of 16 GB used).

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a tool that does it. It's not 100% equivalent to DebugView, but it has some other nice features (like the ability to colorize traces) :-).

It's available here: [TraceSpy](https://github.com/smourier/TraceSpy)

Since it's 100% open source, it contains C# code that demonstrates how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I would start with the [TraceListener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracelistener.aspx) class, although I'm not sure if this can be used to capture Win32 debug tracing.